# Is the product of two Smith Normal Forms a the Smith normal form of the product?

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains, smith-normal-form

Suppose A and B are square matrices of the same size over a PID R. Does the Smith Normal form of AB equal the product of the Smith normal form of A and B?
I think this should be false. However, I can't quite find an example.

Comment: It is false. Try $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Their Smith normal forms are both $A$, but their product's Smith normal form is not $A^2$.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.